# How to fix Error (Xcode): None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named "AppIcon"?

Tags: flutter, xcode, appicon

I am facing the error
Error (Xcode): None of the input catalogs contained a matching stickers icon set or app icon set named  "AppIcon".

And cannot fix it, even though I tried several options (add AppIcon into the folder, re-run xCode and so on), but still the same outcome.

Can someone help me please?

[image]

[image]